# ImportError on ArchLinux ARM

Tags: python, archlinux-arm, python-telegram-bot

I've made a python program that goes online and look for news on some site and if something is found it send me a message on Telegram. I've run my program on my Debian machine and it works, now I want put it on my Raspberry Pi and let it run... So I copieted all the file on my raspberry installed all the necessary library (included https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) but when I run my program with :

```
python2 ./main.py
```

I get:

> ImportError: No module named telebot

What I can do? and why I get this error?
EDIT:

Probably the error is what Bruno9779 said. Those are my output:

```
python2 --version ----> python 2.7.11
python --version  ----> python 3.5.1
env python --version -> python 3.5.1
pip --version --------> pip 2.7.1.2 from /usr/lib/python3.5/site_packages (python 3.5)
```

So I changed my shebang to #!/usr/bin/python2 -tt
(I've also tried with #!/usr/bin/env python2 -tt but I still get the same error)

Comment: The problem is that pip installs packages for python 3.5, which will not be available to python 2.7. Since you are running the script with python2 and not as an executable, the shebang is ignored. Try running the script with python 3.5 and if it does not work install pip for python 2.7 (virtualenv is the cleanes way to go, but there are other ways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what surfaced in the comments of my other answer, it looks like there could be a versión mismatch of sorts.

Try:

```
python2 --version
python --version
env python --version
pip --version
```

To see if there are mismatches.

Since you are calling the script with the command `python2` I guess you are running some sort of virtualenv, where `python` or `python3` point to another version of python.

The versión of pip you use to install packages must be the same as the version you use to run the script

Answer (score 0):

Install telebot with pip:

```
pip install telebot
```

It could be in the AUR, but I am not on Arch now to check

Comment: Do you get the same error if you type: import telebot in the python prompt?

Comment: What is the shebang of main.py?